# Generated primary keys start form 9951 instead of the 10000

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, oracle-xe

I make use of:

NetBeans IDE 6.7.1,
GlassFish v2.1, 
Oracle 10g XE, 
JAVA 6 SE, 
JAVA 5 EE,

From inside a stateless EJB I persist entities of type customer I have the annotation:
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", sequenceName="cust_id_seq") in the class customer so the 
primary keys are autogenerated in the database from the sequence cust_id_seq but when I persist the first customer the primary key is 9951 instead of 10000, the primary key of the second customer is 9952. The output of the GlassFish v2.1 after I persisted two customers is:

Application server startup complete.

My id is: 0

TopLink, version: Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b31g-fcs (10/19/2009))

Server: unknown
file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/IOANNIS_PAPAIOANNOU/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoClub/dist/gfdeploy/VideoClub-ejb_jar/-vc_pu login successful

My id is: 9951

My id is: 0

My id is: 9952

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", sequenceName="cust_id_seq")
public class Customer implements Serializable
{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
@Column(name="CUST_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private int phoneNumber;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "credit")
private int credit;

@OneToMany    
private Collection<CustRentMovie> rents = new ArrayList<CustRentMovie>();

public int getCredit()
{
    return credit;
}

public void setCredit(int credit)
{
    this.credit = credit;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getPhoneNumber()
{
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber)
{
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public Collection<CustRentMovie> getRents()
{
    return rents;
}

public void setRents(Collection<CustRentMovie> rents)
{
    this.rents = rents;
}


}
```

the code of the EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class ClerkSessionBean implements ClerkSessionRemote
{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "vc_pu")
private EntityManager em;

public int writeCustomer(AlmostCustomer almostCustomer)
{

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    System.out.println("My id is: " + customer.getId());
    customer.setFirstName(almostCustomer.getFirstName());
    customer.setLastName(almostCustomer.getLastName());
    customer.setPhoneNumber(almostCustomer.getPhoneNumber());
    em.persist(customer);
    System.out.println("My id is: " + customer.getId());
    return customer.getId();
}
}
```

part of the script that creates the database:

```
CREATE table customer
(
cust_id NUMBER(5),
phone_number NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
-- Τα χρήματα που έχει ένας πελάτης στο λογαριασμό του.
credit NUMBER(5, 2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT cust_pk PRIMARY KEY (cust_id),
-- Μόνο ένας λογαριασμός για κάθε σπίτι.
CONSTRAINT phone_unique UNIQUE (phone_number)
)
/

DROP SEQUENCE cust_id_seq
/

CREATE SEQUENCE cust_id_seq MINVALUE 10000 MAXVALUE 99999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 10000 NOCACHE  NOCYCLE ORDER
```

/

Yiannis P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the customer entity in the annotation @SequenceGenerator I added the atribute allocationSize with value 1, now the primary keys start from 10000.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", sequenceName="cust_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class Customer implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    @Column(name="CUST_ID")
    private int id;  
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should change `CREATE SEQUENCE cust_id_seq ... INCREMENT BY`**`1`** to `... INCREMENT BY`**`50`**.  Here is why.

The declared sequence increment should match the `@SequenceGenerator`'s `allocationSize` parameter. `allocationSize` is not specified and therefore defaults to 50.  But the true `INCREMENT BY` is only 1, not 50.  So there is a mismatch between `allocationSize` and the real `INCREMENT BY`.

Here's how this mismatch could cause the problem.  TopLink Essentials (TLE) calls `NEXTVAL()` on `cust_id_seq`.  The sequence returns 10000 + 1.  TLE assumes the sequence just incremented by 50 (default JPA `allocationSize`) instead of 1 (actual amount).  TLE subtracts `allocationSize` = 50 from 10001 to get 9951.

By the way, if you have the freedom to do so,  consider upgrading to TLE's successor, [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) (and to [Glassfish v3](http://glassfish.java.net/)).

Comment: +1 You are correct on the whole line. 1) Yes, the `allocationSize` of sequence generator must match with the increment value of the sequence in database. 2) Yes, that's how the algorithm works on the TLE side. 3) Yes, the default `allocationSize` is 50 with JPA 1.0 too.

Comment: I am on vacation right now I will try your solution next week.

Comment: I changed in the sequence cust_id_seq the INCREMENT BY 1 to INCREMENT BY 50 but still the first primary key has the value 9951, the second 9952, the third 9953